# Запись полученного значения в ячейку существующей таблицы Excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

Каким образом можно записать полученное значение в определенную ячейку существующей таблицы с сохранением форматирования? Заранее благодарен за ответ.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

    wb = load_workbook(filename = 'таблица 1-8.xlsx')
    sheet_ranges = wb['Таблица 5']
    ws1 = wb.active
    sheet = wb['Таблица 5']

    def udav():
        summ = 0
        x = 2
        while sheet.cell(row=x, column=3).value is not None:
            Nk = sheet.cell(row=x, column=3).value
            Nl = sheet.cell(row=x, column=4).value
            Gvv = sheet.cell(row=x, column=5).value
            nksr = sheet.cell(row=x, column=6).value
            value = Nk*Nl*Gvv*nksr   
            x = x + 1  
            summ += value

        else:
            return summ

    xudav = udav() 
    print(xudav)
```

Comment: Уточните суть вопроса.... Если записать новое значение в существующую ячейку `sheet["A3"].value = <new_val>`, то форматирование должно сохранится

Comment: Я имел в виду запись в ячейку другой существующей таблицы Excel, с последующим сохранением этой таблицы.

Comment: у вас непонятно сформулирован вопрос - можете привести пример того, что вы хотите сделать / получить?

Comment: Мне нужно извлечь значения из имеющейся таблицы и провести с ними какие-то действия, что я сделал в коде который приложил, после этого, полученное значение мне нужно записать в другую таблицу, в определенную ячейку, не перезаписывая таблицу, а именно открывая существующую.

Comment: другая таблица - это другой лист или другой Excel файл?

Comment: Другой Excel файл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

fn1 = r"C:\temp\test1.xlsx"
fn2 = r"C:\temp\test2.xlsx"

wb1 = load_workbook(fn1)
wb2 = load_workbook(fn2)

ws1 = wb1["Sheet1"]
ws2 = wb2["Sheet1"]

cell_coord = "E10"

ws2[cell_coord].value = calc_value(ws1)
wb2.save(fn2)

wb1.close()
wb2.close()
```

Comment: Премного благодарен!